# Getting Active View Object Parameters?

Tags: revit-api

I am new to the API and I'm trying to get values from the active view.  I am using the following code as a mock up to what I'm trying to do:

```
public void GetViewProperties()
{
  String viewname;
  String typename;
  String levelname;
  String Output;

  ViewFamilyType VfamType;
  Level lev;

  //Get document and current view
  Document doc = this.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
  View currentView = this.ActiveUIDocument.ActiveView;

  //Find the view family type that matches the active view
  VfamType = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(ViewFamilyType))
    .Where(q => q.Name == "1-0-Model").First() as ViewFamilyType;

  //Find the level that matches the active view
  lev = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(Level))
    .Where(q => q.Name == "00").First() as Level;

  //Get the view's current name
  viewname = currentView.Name.ToString();

  //Get the name of the view family type
  typename = VfamType.Name;
  //Get the name of the level
  levelname = lev.Name.ToString();

  //Combine results for task dialog
  Output = "View: " + viewname + "\n" + typename + "-" + levelname;
  //Show results
  TaskDialog.Show("View Properties Test",Output);
}
```

I'm cheating at the moment by grabbing the view type and level by name.  I really want them to be found by looking at the properties of the active view.  I can't figure out how I am meant to access the view type and level name properties.  I need to make lambda use a variable e.g. (q => q.Name == Level.name), (q => q.Name == ViewFamilyType.name).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code corrected:

```
public void GetViewProperties()
{
  //Get document and current view
  Document doc = this.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
  View currentView = this.ActiveUIDocument.ActiveView;

  //Find the view family type that matches the active view
  var VfamType = (ViewFamilyType)doc.GetElement(currentView.GetTypeId());

  //Find the level that matches the active view
  Level lev = currentView.GenLevel;

  //Get the view's current name
  string viewname = currentView.Name;

  //Get the name of the view family type
  string typename = VfamType.Name;

  //Get the name of the level
  string levelname = lev.Name;

  //Combine results for task dialog
  string Output = "View: " + viewname + "\n" + typename + "-" + levelname;

  //Show results
  TaskDialog.Show("View Properties Test", Output);
}
```

You don't need to use a `FilteredElementCollector` to get these informations. And if you need elsewhere, you don't need a `Where`: just put your lambda in the `First`:

```
new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(ViewFamilyType))
  .First(q => q.Name == "1-0-Model")
```

If you need to access in your lambda a property specific to a class, not defined on `Element`, you can use `Cast`:

```
new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(ViewFamilyType))
  .Cast<ViewFamilyType>().First(vft => vft.IsValidDefaultTemplate)
```

And please do not declare all your variable at the start of your methods. You're not writing Pascal. Declare variables as close to the first spot that you use them as possible. It makes your code much more readable. The closer a variable is declared to where it is used, the less scrolling/searching you have to do when reading the code later and it also naturally narrow their scope.

Comment: The code works exactly as it should so thanks.  Much clearer now and point taken on declaring variables, I was being over tidy and still relatively new to programming!  Only question is about using a var.  Isn't it best to declare a type?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for **View.GenLevel** property. This will work for views related to levels, such as Plan Views. Note that if this View is not generated by a level, this property is null.

Comment: That's what I thought. Also the Object type property seems to store the view type that I'm after. I tried ToString() but it doesn't give the desired result. I just want the view's level name and type name. Do I need to store the genlevel to find it in the doc and then pull it's properties?